# jQuery Plugin to update live a <li> from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-plugins, live

is there any jQuery plugin to create something like the live feed from the [Twitter Main Page](http://www.twitter.com) , using PHP, which is getting the data from a MySQL database?
How has to be the PHP file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really don't need a plugin for this, you could easily create something similar yourself using jQuery to make AJAX calls to a PHP MySQL feed

Create a script to make reoccurring AJAX calls using [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and then add the new found results to the feed container using [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>Tweets</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#tweets {
    width: 500px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#tweets li {
    background-color: #E5EECC;
    margin: 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.author {
    font-weight: bold
}
.date {
    font-size: 10px;
}
</style>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("showNewTweets()", 1000);
});

function showNewTweets() {
    $.getJSON("feed.php", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            $("#tweets").prepend($("<li><span class=\"author\">" + data.author + "</span> " +  data.tweet + "<br /><span class=\"date\">" + data.date + "</span></li>").fadeIn("slow"));
        }
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="tweets"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array( "author" => "someone",
                        "tweet" => "The time is: " . time(), 
                        "date" => date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')));
?>
```

Comment: Can you put an example of code. I don't know jQuery a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I'll post an example a little bit later today.

Comment: You shouldn't be forming the element in the Javascript - form it in the PHP. Here's why. What happens when your markup changes? The form contained in your Javascript is now deprecated, and the new `<li>` will be different from the others on the page.

Also, shouldn't that be `setInterval(showNewTweets, 1000)`? I know in jQuery you're not supposed to put the `()` on a function name as an argument.

Comment: This makes a loop with the last. How to limit to only 10 messages? And, it's possible to encode various messages in JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "encode various messages" in JSON but depending on what you're trying to do, I'd guess yes. You can also use XML rather than JSON if that floats your boat.

As for truncating the line items, you'd want to use .remove() http://api.jquery.com/remove/ in combination with $("#tweets ul li:last").  Check the length (e.g. number of LIs) and remove the last LIs until you have only 10 LIs total.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Can you put an example of remove, please?

Comment: Sorry this gravy train is done.  You have the tools and references at your fingertips to solve the problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() would be more adequate, since you want a check at regular intervals.

Then, there is a jquery comet plugin that explores the implementation of the "push" technology. [Check it out here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet).

Answer (score 0):

```
var frequency = 5000,  // number of milliseconds between updates.

    updater   = function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://twitter.com/example/something.html',
            success: function(data) {
                // update your page based upon the value of data, e.g.:
                jQuery('ul#feed').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
            }
        });
    },

    interval  = setInterval(updater, frequency);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var frequency = 10000; // 10 seconds = 10000

            var updater   = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'mesaj.html', // data source html php
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#message").html(data); // div id
                    }
                }); 
            };

            interval  = setInterval(updater, frequency);
        });
</script>
```

## example

```
<div id="message">{ do not write }</div>
```