# jQuery Live Feed only display 10 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I recently found [this code snippet solution on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798785/jquery-plugin-to-update-live-a-li-from-php).

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>Tweets</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#tweets {
    width: 500px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#tweets li {
    background-color: #E5EECC;
    margin: 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.author {
    font-weight: bold
}
.date {
    font-size: 10px;
}
</style>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("showNewTweets()", 1000);
});

function showNewTweets() {
    $.getJSON("feed.php", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            $("#tweets").prepend($("<li><span class=\"author\">" + data.author + "</span> " +  data.tweet + "<br /><span class=\"date\">" + data.date + "</span></li>").fadeIn("slow"));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array( "author" => "someone",
                        "tweet" => "The time is: " . time(), 
                        "date" => date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')));
?>
```

It works great for me, but I want it constantly (every 3 seconds) look if there is a new tweet available, and if so it should add the tweet on top of the list. The list should have a maximum of only 10 `<li></li>` items. If there are more then 1 new tweets, it should just add 1 new tweet, and after another 3 seconds, it should load another new tweet (if available).

How can I add this limitation?

Thanks

Comment: "This" is which exactly?..

Comment: @nicael as written in my question, the script from the answer marked as solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually provided the snippet you are intrested in. Also, mind showing us any of your attempts?

Comment: @CristianD I thought it's stupid copy and paste the script from the other stackoverflow page, but if you want me to I add it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("showNewTweets()", 1000);
});

function showNewTweets() {
    var tweets = 0;
    $("#tweets").html('');
    $.getJSON("feed.php", null, function(data) {
        if (data != null || tweets <= 10) {
            $("#tweets").prepend($("<li><span class=\"author\">" + data.author + "</span> " +  data.tweet + "<br /><span class=\"date\">" + data.date + "</span></li>").fadeIn("slow"));
            tweets++;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Empty the list and add only the last 10 tweets by using some sort of counter. The code execution will stop at the 10th tweet or when there are no tweets to display.

Also, in the PHP code generating the array, you might want to `array_flip` it before encoding the array.

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is the whole list would go away and reload the new one (for example if there are more then 10 new items within the reload time), which leads to the problem that it doesn't look good, and some tweets are getting lost.

Comment: The only way to display the last 10 tweets is, well, to remove the previous result and reinsert the last 10 tweets at the time the call was made.

Comment: I thought about showing 10 tweets and constantly (for example every 3 seconds) adding a new one on top (if there is a new one). And in total there should be more then 10 tweets displayed.